# I want to add a new product to firebase if its Id isn't existed in the favorite section

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-realtime-database

i am making a shop app and i want every account to have its own favorite products , so i am trying to add the product the user added to favorite to its profile section in "Firebase", and it's okay with modifying the case from favorite to not , but the problem is i want to only add the product if the id isn't exist in that section.

but it duplicate the record and modify it too , not just add or modify

Here's the code :

```
Future<void> testFavourite(String id,uid) async {
    final url = 'https://test.firebaseio.com/profiles/.json';
    final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));
    final profileData = jsonDecode(response.body) as Map<String,dynamic>;
    String profile;
    profileData.forEach((key, value) async {
      if(value['uid'] == uid){
        profile = key;
        final profileUrl = 'https://test.firebaseio.com/profiles/$profile/favProducts.json';
        if(value['favProducts'] == null){
          await http.post(Uri.parse(profileUrl),body: jsonEncode({
              'id' : id,
              'isFavorite' : true,
          }));
        }
        if(value['favProducts'] != null){
         final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(profileUrl));
         final favProducts = jsonDecode(response.body) as Map<String,dynamic>;
         favProducts.forEach((key,product) async{
           if(product['id'] == id){
             final productUrl = 'https://test.firebaseio.com'
                 '/profiles/$profile/favProducts/$key.json';
             await http.patch(Uri.parse(productUrl),body: jsonEncode({
               'isFavorite' : !product['isFavorite']
             }));
           }
           if(product['id'] != id){
            
            await http.post(Uri.parse(productUrl),body: jsonEncode({
               'id' : id,
               'isFavorite' : true,
             }));
           }
         });
        }
      }
    });
  }
```

[image: Here's the firebase]

Comment: So what's the error that you are getting?

Comment: when i type this code : 
if(value["id"] != id){
//code to post new product// 
}
it modify the existed product and also create a new one